# Unknown column in field list after trying to create OneToMany relationship

Tags: spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to create a `@OneToMany` relationship in hibernate. I need to store a list of voters for every article in the database. Each vote has a userId and a vote number. My project compiles and runs, but when I try access the `@OneToMany` column it doesn't exist and throws the error in the title.

I've looked at some other questions on here, but none of them seem to answer this specific question. I want to use a list because it makes it way easier in my controller.

Here are my entities, I left out most of the fields in article and getters and setters because they aren't really important to this question.

Article:

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name="articles")
    public class Article implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "votes")
        private int votes;

        @Column(name = "voters")
        @ElementCollection
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vote", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Vote> voters = new ArrayList<>();
```

Vote:

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "vote")
    public class Vote {

        public Vote(long userId, int vote){
            setUserId(userId);
            setVote(vote);
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;

        @ManyToOne
        private Article article;

        @Column(name = "userId")
        private long userId;

        @Column(name = "vote")
        private int vote; //either 1, 0, or -1

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
```

Error:

```java
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'voters' in 'field list'
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:974) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        (the stack trace continues but I didn't think it was important)
```

The error only occurs when I try to access the column in my controller class and during queries.

This is the query that I want to make:

```java
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "UPDATE articles SET voters = ?1 WHERE id = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
int updateArticleVoters(List<Vote> newVoters, long id);
```

I just need a way to store basically a 2D array in the database. I don't know if there is an easier way to do it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: it seems the rror is in your sql schema, it seems it is not defined properly. Do you use some kind of migration to update your sql schema in hibernate

Comment: normally when I change things on the server side I have to drop the table from the database and then when I run the app again it rebuilds everything with the correct structure. This time it did not insert the correct column for voters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First mistake:  you can't use `@Column` on an association, you must use `@JoinColumn`.

Second mistake: `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "something")` means that the `@JoinColumn` is on the other entity (owning side).

Third mistake: `@ElementCollection` means that you want a collection of non-entities (Strings, Embeddables or Basic types), but here `Vote` is an entity.

The mapping in `Article` should be:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private List<Vote> voters = new ArrayList<>();
```

Fourth mistake: in your `UPDATE` native query, you can't set `Article.voters` as it's not a column but a JPA one-to-many collection mapped to the many-to-one `Vote.article`. That is basic JPA, you'd better read the docs about `@ManyToOne` management before proceeding.

eg. https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby

Comment: I get this error with that annotation: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.serverApp.serverApp.models.Vote.articles in com.serverApp.serverApp.models.Article.voters`

Comment: Here, the error says you wrote mappedBy="articles". Please write mappedBy="article" as in my answer. The "mappedBy" must equal the name of the owning side property.

Comment: How would I access the voters data in a query then? When I read in an article from the database and then try to access the voters list it says there is no column 'voters' in field list.

Comment: This is the query that I need to perform to update the list of voters. I know it is incorrect but do you know what the correct equivalent woud be? `@Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "UPDATE articles SET voters = ?1 WHERE id = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    int updateArticleVoters(List<Vote> newVoters, long id);`

Comment: Did you remove `@Column(name = "voters")`and `@ElementCollection`? If yes, it shouldn't complain about a missing `voters` column.
To access voters, you could use `Article.voters`!
You can't use a native query to update the `voters` collection, otherwise it will say there is no `voters` column! You should update the owning side (the article_id join column in Voter). You can do that in Java: `voter.setArticle(article)` - the cascade is not sufficient. Do you understand?

Comment: Yes! Thank you I got everything to work the way I wanted